# tiovx-app-host error on arago yocto project on cunstom AM57xx board

Tags: opencv, yocto, openembedded, openvx, arago

I'm trying to compile `tiovx-app-host` for arago yocto(`ROCKO`) project for AM57xx-evm board its compiled, But same for my custom am57xx board gives an error regarding `ld`. Even I did not changed **tiovx-app-host.bb** file.

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
NOTE: make -j 3 TARGET_ROOTDIR=/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot GCCLINARO=/home/sangeet/toolchain/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf TIOVXPATH=/home//am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-tiovx-lib-tree IPCPATH=/home_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree SDKPLATFORMIFPATH=/home/am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-tiovx-lib-tree/sys-iface PROC_LIST=host khronos_example
#
#
# Making host ...
# Making khronos_example ...
make -C host PROCLIST="host khronos_example"
make -C khronos_example PROCLIST="host khronos_example"
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/c_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/host'
#
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example'
# Making all ...
make PROFILE=debug app_host
#
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/host'
# Making all ...
make PROFILE=debug opticalflow
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example'
#
#
/home/sangeet/toolchain/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -MD -MF vx_platform.o.dep -I/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include -Wall -ffloat-store -fPIC -Wunused -pthread -Dfar= -ggdb -D DEBUG -O0 -I. -I.. -I/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-tiovx-lib-tree/sys-iface -I/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/VX -DOPENVX_INCLUDE -I/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/include -I/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/packages  -D_REENTRANT `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -c -o vx_platform.o ../host/vx_platform.c
# Making bin/debug/obj/main_host.ov7A ...
/home/sangeet/toolchain/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -MD -MF bin/debug/obj/main_host.ov7A.dep  -D_REENTRANT -I/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include -Wall -ffloat-store -fPIC -Wunused -pthread -Dfar= -ggdb -D DEBUG -I. -I.. -I/home/c_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-tiovx-lib-tree/sys-iface -I/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/VX -DOPENVX_INCLUDE -I/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/include -I/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/packages -o bin/debug/obj/main_host.ov7A main_host.c
# Making bin/debug/obj/vx_platform.ov7A ...
/home/sangeet/toolchain/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -MD -MF bin/debug/obj/vx_platform.ov7A.dep  -D_REENTRANT -I/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include -Wall -ffloat-store -fPIC -Wunused -pthread -Dfar= -ggdb -D DEBUG -I. -I.. -I/home//_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-tiovx-lib-tree/sys-iface -I/home/c_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/VX -DOPENVX_INCLUDE -I/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/include -I/home/_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/packages -o bin/debug/obj/vx_platform.ov7A vx_platform.c
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
main_host.c: In function ‘main’:
main_host.c:83:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘TestModuleRegister’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         TestModuleRegister();
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main_host.c:84:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘tivx_set_debug_zone’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         tivx_set_debug_zone(0);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main_host.c:86:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘vx_conformance_test_main’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         vx_conformance_test_main(argc, argv);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../host/vx_platform.c: In function ‘System_ipcNotifyRecvFxn’:
../host/vx_platform.c:582:11: warning: variable ‘status’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     Int32 status;
           ^~~~~~
vx_platform.c: In function ‘System_ipcNotifyRecvFxn’:
vx_platform.c:582:11: warning: variable ‘status’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     Int32 status;
           ^~~~~~
../host/vx_platform.c: In function ‘System_ovxAllocMem’:
../host/vx_platform.c:660:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     ptr = HeapMem_alloc (0, size, 4096);
         ^
vx_platform.c: In function ‘System_ovxAllocMem’:
vx_platform.c:660:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     ptr = HeapMem_alloc (0, size, 4096);
         ^
../host/vx_platform.c:651:22: warning: unused variable ‘prms’ [-Wunused-variable]
     CMEM_AllocParams prms;
                      ^~~~
vx_platform.c:651:22: warning: unused variable ‘prms’ [-Wunused-variable]
     CMEM_AllocParams prms;
                      ^~~~
vx_platform.c: In function ‘System_ovxFreeMem’:
../host/vx_platform.c: In function ‘System_ovxFreeMem’:
vx_platform.c:672:22: warning: unused variable ‘prms’ [-Wunused-variable]
     CMEM_AllocParams prms;
                      ^~~~
../host/vx_platform.c:672:22: warning: unused variable ‘prms’ [-Wunused-variable]
     CMEM_AllocParams prms;
                      ^~~~
../host/vx_platform.c:685:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
vx_platform.c:685:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
/home/sangeet/toolchain/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -MD -MF tialloc.o.dep -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include -Wall -ffloat-store -fPIC -Wunused -pthread -Dfar= -ggdb -D DEBUG -O0 -I. -I.. -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-tiovx-lib-tree/sys-iface -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/VX -DOPENVX_INCLUDE -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/include -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/packages  -D_REENTRANT `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -c -o tialloc.o ../host/tialloc.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++  -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot  -D_REENTRANT `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include -Wall -ffloat-store -fPIC -Wunused -pthread -Dfar= -ggdb -D DEBUG -O0 -I. -I.. -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-tiovx-lib-tree/sys-iface -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/VX -DOPENVX_INCLUDE -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/include -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/packages -c solution_exercise1.cpp
#
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
# Making bin/debug/obj/tialloc.ov7A ...
/home/sangeet/toolchain/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -MD -MF bin/debug/obj/tialloc.ov7A.dep  -D_REENTRANT -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include -Wall -ffloat-store -fPIC -Wunused -pthread -Dfar= -ggdb -D DEBUG -I. -I.. -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-tiovx-lib-tree/sys-iface -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/VX -DOPENVX_INCLUDE -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/include -I/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/packages -o bin/debug/obj/tialloc.ov7A tialloc.c
../host/tialloc.c: In function ‘HeapMem_init’:
tialloc.c: In function ‘HeapMem_init’:
../host/tialloc.c:304:4: warning: ‘memset’ used with constant zero length parameter; this could be due to transposed parameters [-Wmemset-transposed-args]
    memset ((char *)block_base, size, 0);
    ^~~~~~
tialloc.c:304:4: warning: ‘memset’ used with constant zero length parameter; this could be due to transposed parameters [-Wmemset-transposed-args]
    memset ((char *)block_base, size, 0);
    ^~~~~~
#
# Making bin/debug/app_host ...
/home/sangeet/toolchain/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/src/api/.libs/ -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/src/utils/.libs -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/src/transport/.libs -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/lib -ggdb -Wall -Wl,-Map=bin/debug/app_host.map -o bin/debug/app_host bin/debug/obj/main_host.ov7A bin/debug/obj/vx_platform.ov7A bin/debug/obj/tialloc.ov7A -lpthread -lc -lrt -lm -lticmem -Wl,--start-group  -lvx_tiovx_tests -lvx_kernels_openvx_core -lvx_conformance_tests -lvx_conformance_engine -lvx_conformance_tests_testmodule -lvx_vxu -lvx_platform_vision_sdk_linux -lvx_framework -Wl,--end-group  -ltiipc -ltiipcutils -ltitransportrpmsg
solution_exercise1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
solution_exercise1.cpp:162:16: warning: unused variable ‘trackable_kp_ratio_thr’ [-Wunused-variable]
     vx_float32 trackable_kp_ratio_thr  = 0.8f;                  // threshold for the ration of tracked keypoints to all
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
#CPP flags:  -D_REENTRANT
#LD flags: -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/src/api/.libs/ -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/src/utils/.libs -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/src/transport/.libs -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/lib -ggdb -O0 -Wall -Wl,-Map=bin/debug/opticalflow.map -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib
# Making bin/debug/opticalflow ...
/home/sangeet/toolchain/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/src/api/.libs/ -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/src/utils/.libs -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ti/ti-ipc-tree/linux/src/transport/.libs -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib -L/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/lib -ggdb -O0 -Wall -Wl,-Map=bin/debug/opticalflow.map -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib -o bin/debug/opticalflow vx_platform.o tialloc.o solution_exercise1.o -lpthread -lc -lrt -lm -lticmem -lstdc++ -Wl,--start-group -lvx_kernels_openvx_core -lvx_platform_vision_sdk_linux -lvx_framework -Wl,--end-group `pkg-config --libs opencv` -ltbb -lz -ludev -ltiipc -ltiipcutils -ltitransportrpmsg
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
/home/sangeet/toolchain/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libcap.so.2, needed by /home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/lib/libudev.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
solution_exercise1.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:625: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:667: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:571: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:682: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `cv::String::String(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.inl.hpp:81: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `CGuiModule::CGuiModule(char const*)':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:53: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(cv::String const&)'
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:56: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const'
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:63: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:53: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `CGuiModule::CGuiModule(int)':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:68: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)'
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:72: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const'
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:79: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:68: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `CGuiModule::GetWidth()':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:85: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::get(int) const'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `CGuiModule::Grab()':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:114: undefined reference to `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:116: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&)'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `CGuiModule::DrawText(int, int, char const*)':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:120: undefined reference to `cv::putText(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::String const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `CGuiModule::DrawPoint(int, int)':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:130: undefined reference to `cv::circle(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `CGuiModule::DrawArrow(int, int, int, int)':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:141: undefined reference to `cv::line(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:142: undefined reference to `cv::line(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:143: undefined reference to `cv::line(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `CGuiModule::Show()':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:150: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `CGuiModule::AbortRequested()':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:156: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:159: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
solution_exercise1.o: In function `CGuiModule::WaitForKey()':
/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example/opencv_camera_display.h:171: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/host'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/host'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:78: recipe for target 'bin/debug/opticalflow' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/debug/opticalflow] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example'
makefile:55: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/git/khronos_example'
makefile:49: recipe for target 'khronos_example' failed
make: *** [khronos_example] Error 2
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
WARNING: /home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/temp/run.do_compile.14916:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/sangeet/source/user_am57x/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/am5728_core_rdk-linux-gnueabi/tiovx-app-host/01.00.01.00-r2/temp/log.do_compile.14916)
```

Comment: `pkg-config: command not found` is your problem. install the package.

Comment: I have installed still same error @OleksandrKravchuk if pkg-config is     the problem how it will compile for evk board or should i need any changes to my boad conf file

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk you are correct. i added pkgconfig and works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `inherit pkgconfig` to my recipe and its working fine.